# hidesBackButton is not working, even though in viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem, navigationcontroller

I have seen similar questions, but those questions are all very old. I'm trying to hide the 'back' button in my ViewController. Now, it looks like this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ipmbqgxji574j06/Screenshot%202020-07-21%2020.25.17.png?dl=0

**My code** *(I've tried implementing it in both viewWillAppear & viewDidLoad, neither seem to work)*:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    
    // Setting up title of ViewController
    self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = "Groceries"
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: true)
    print(self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton)
    // Returns true
}
```

**I have also tried putting the code in prepareForSegue:**

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?){
    if segue.identifier == K.welcomeSegue{
    let objVC = segue.destination as? TableViewController
    objVC?.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
  }
}
```

Could anyone help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

To hide the `backButton` on `navigationBar` either set the `navigationButton` as nil and then hide it or hide it directly.

A combination of these to approaches would be a better solution and works even if you have set a custom `navigationBar`.

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
```

You can also use

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: false)
}
```